# adding a drop down button alongside with my other buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some buttons in navigation bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/wKHaT/8/

```
<div class="mynav">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class=""><a href="192.168.1.100/aaa">AAA</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="192.168.1.100/aaa">BBB</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="192.168.1.100/aaa">CCC</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="192.168.1.100/aaa">DDD</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="192.168.1.100/aaa">EEE</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- Split button -->
<div class="btn-group mynav">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The number of my buttons are too much so I should use drop-down buttons. Here there are two problems:

1- the style of my drop down button does not look like the other buttons. any way to solve it? (drop-down button should not appear with bigger size)

2- the other problem is that i want by clicking on my button it goes to a link. i can do it by onclick but onclick is not a seo friendly way.

Comment: If you put the `ul` inside of the action button and have it as `position: relative;` it will inherit their styles as well as be relative to that button size. Here is a dropdown I made for a previous question to show you how it follows it's parent `li` Link --> http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/XvQRH/ . Maybe you should just do a CSS3 dropdown like the one in this fiddle for only that button unless you want them all to be `li`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #1, Adjust the styling on your pills to match the button:

```
.nav-pills li a {padding: 7px 15px; font-weight: bold;}
```

OR vice-versa:

```
a.btn {padding: 4px 15px;}
button.dropdown-toggle {padding: 4px 8px;}
```

For #2, make your button an anchor instead:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Action</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wKHaT/14

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wKHaT/15

Answer (score -1):

1.
try this for your style:

[http://jsfiddle.net/wKHaT/10/][1]

2.
onclick event souldn't do negativ rating for your seo